Feedback on Multi-Process Software Architecture
I am building an embedded linux system where fault tolerance is important. There are multiple independent tasks, say {P1, P2, P3} that do not need to share any system resources, so I chose to split them into individual daemons started on boot automatically by systemd. This way any failures in the individual processes don’t affect the others, and also results in simpler codebase. Additionally, debugging multi-threaded code is cumbersome.
On a global view, I want the system to operate in three modes, say {A, B, C}. The mode can be changed during runtime by process P1, so I want the other processes to change their behaviour accordingly when this happens. So at any given time P1 knows the latest state which must be somehow accessible to P2 and P3 as well.
My solution was for P1 to write to a known file at start-up, say “/tmp/mode” that contains the current mode. When a mode change happens, I’d send a signal SIGUSR1 to P2 and P3, so that they go read the latest mode. In a way I want a global variable “mode” that can be read by other processes at any time. That way if P2 or P3 crashes and restarts, it can still query the current mode and continue correctly.
I’m looking for feedback on this design. What are potential flaws you see? Can you recommend similar/better examples of such systems? What are some ways to make this more robust?

Multiple processes is multi threaded code. It just forces the threads to communicate thru a well defined API. But that does not in itself solve all the problems with multi threading.

I find that the Erlang OTP library is a very good inspiration for handling fault tolerance. The library has a set of suggestions on how to handle faulty systems and how to restart. You don´t need to use the, admittedly special, language of Erlang to be inspired by their architecture.

If it makes the code easier to read/debug and the system easier to reason about, then your decision to use three separate applications is a good one.
Your reasoning for using a file to communicate the current mode to the various processes is also sound. My main concern there is in the location of the file, as the /tmp folder can be occasionally cleaned out and might not be preserved over a full reboot.
Furthermore, you should consider how P1 can update the /tmp/mode file with the least risk of corrupting it due to crashing/being killed at the wrong moment.
What you didn't mention, and might be too much for a question here, but what is critical for a fault-tolerant system is that you define what should happen when a fault happened despite your best efforts to avoid it. What should happen if the mode file isn't readable? What should happen if the three processes end up disagreeing on what system mode is active (e.g. P1 believes it has written mode A, but P2 has read mode B)?
You don't have to answer those questions here, but you should think about them and account for them in your architecture. And note that the solution can involve human intervention and/or detection if the possibility for the fault is low enough.
